# LinQ C# - Grouping a list of objects depending on strings contained in their List<string> property

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections, group-by

I have a problem with grouping on a List of strings.

My class "Post" contains a List property called Tags:

```
public class Post
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Somewhere else in my code I am gathering all my posts in a List. Now, many of these posts share tags with each other. Assume:

```
Post_1.Tags = new List<string>(){"a", "b", "c"};
Post_2.Tags = new List<string>(){"a", "d", "e"};
Post_3.Tags = new List<string>(){"b", "c", "d"};
Post_4.Tags = new List<string>(){"c", "d", "f"};
```

I am trying to obtain a collection with this kind of structure:

```
Key: a; Values: Post_1, Post_2;
Key: b; Values: Post_1, Post_3;
Key: c; Values: Post_1, Post_3, Post_4;
Key: d; Values: Post_2, Post_3, Post_4;
Key: e; Values: Post_2;
Key: f; Values: Post_4;
```

I guess I need to use GroupBy(), but I'm stuck with the syntax, since:

```
List<Post> Posts = // all my posts
ILookup<string, Post> ByTag = Posts.GroupBy(p => p.Tags) ...
```

is obviously targeting the List of tags and not the single tags.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var tags = Posts.SelectMany(p => p.Tags).Distinct();
var groups = from p in Posts
    from t in tags.Where(tag => p.Tags.Contains(tag))
    group p by t
    into gr
    select gr;
```

**Explanation**
SelectMany.Distinct - makes IEnumerable, which contains all tags from all posts without duplicates.
First 2 from - joins tags and posts. Condition of joining - post should contain tag. Resulting collection will every possible pair of post and it's tag.
Group will group those pairs in a way, that gr's key will be a tag and gr will be collection of all posts with that tag. I got used to dictionaries and wrote a code which can be later used converted to `Dictionary<string, List<Post>>` by calling `ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList())`. If you want a Lookup, you don't need group part:

```
var tags = Posts.SelectMany(p => p.Tags).Distinct();
var postAndTagPairs = from p in Posts
    from t in tags.Where(tag => p.Tags.Contains(tag))
    select new {t, p};
var lookup = postAndTagPairs.ToLookup(pat => pat.t, pat => pat.p);
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! It is also possible to specify a function in the Where clause to make the tag-post relation more flexible and advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get a distinct list of tags. Assuming the posts are in a list like this:

```
var posts = new List<Post>
{
    new Post { Tags = new List<string>(){"a", "b", "c"} },
    new Post { Tags = new List<string>(){"a", "d", "e"} },
    new Post { Tags = new List<string>(){"b", "c", "d"} },
    new Post { Tags = new List<string>(){"c", "d", "f"} }
};
```

You get the tags like this:

```
var allTags = posts.SelectMany(p => p.Tags).Distinct();
```

Then you can do your grouping:

```
var result = from p in posts
             from t in allTags.Where(t => p.Tags.Contains(t))
             group p by t into grp
             select grp;
```

Comment: I'll try this, thanks. For the sake of knowledge, how would you write that with LinQ methods?

Comment: It's working, but not exactly how I would expect it. Your code returns a IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Tag>, what I'm going after would be IEnumerable<string, IEnumerable<Tag>>

Comment: I'm confused, IEnumerable doesn't have two type parameters?

Comment: Uhm...nope! IEnumerable is the interface for a non-generic collection, which may or not may be indexed on a key. Lists and arrays are both IEnumerables:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx